# Decouple dequeue operation from gradient/loss computation

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently trying to move away from using feeds and start using queues in order to support larger datasets. Using queues works fine for the optimizers in tensorflow, since they only evaluate the gradient once for each dequeue operation. However, I have implemented interfaces with other optimizers that perform line searches, and I need to evaluate not just the gradient, but also the loss at multiple points for the same batch. Unfortunately, with the normal queueing system each loss evaluation will execute a dequeue instead of computing for the same batch several times.

Is there a way to decouple the dequeuing operation from the gradient/loss computation in such a way that I can execute dequeue once and then execute the gradient/loss computation several times on the current batch?

Edit: Please note that the size of my input tensor is variable between batches. We work with molecular data, and each molecule has a different number of atoms. This is quite different from image data, where everything is typically scaled to have identical dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decouple it by creating a variable stores dequeued value, and then depend on this variable instead of dequeue op. Advancing the queue happens during  `assign`

**Solution #1**: fixed size data, use Variables

```
(image_batch_live,) = tf.train.batch([image],batch_size=5,num_threads=1,capacity=614)

image_batch = tf.Variable(
  tf.zeros((batch_size, image_size, image_size, color_channels)),
  trainable=False,
  name="input_values_cached")

advance_batch = tf.assign(image_batch, image_batch_live)
```

Now `image_batch` gives latest value of queue without advancing it and `advance_batch` advances the queue.

**Solution #2**: variable size data, use persistent Tensors

Here we decouple the workflow by introducing `dequeue_op` and `dequeue_op2`. All computation depends on `dequeue_op2` which is fed the saved value of `dequeue_op`. Using `get_session_tensor/get_session_handle` ensures that actual data remains in TensorFlow runtime and the value that's passed through `feed_dict` is a short string identifier. The API is a little awkward because of `dummy_handle`, I've brought up this issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6131)

```
import tensorflow as tf
def create_session():
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(operation_timeout_in_ms=3000))
    return sess

tf.reset_default_graph()

sess = create_session()
dt = tf.int32
dummy_handle = sess.run(tf.get_session_handle(tf.constant(1)))
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=20, dtypes=[dt])
enqueue_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dt, shape=[None])
enqueue_op = q.enqueue(enqueue_placeholder)
dequeue_op = q.dequeue()
size_op = q.size()

dequeue_handle_op = tf.get_session_handle(dequeue_op)
dequeue_placeholder, dequeue_op2 = tf.get_session_tensor(dummy_handle, dt)
compute_op1 = tf.reduce_sum(dequeue_op2)
compute_op2 = tf.reduce_sum(dequeue_op2)+1


# fill queue with variable size data
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={enqueue_placeholder:[1]*(i+1)})
sess.run(q.close())

try:
    while(True):
        dequeue_handle = sess.run(dequeue_handle_op) # advance the queue
        val1 = sess.run(compute_op1, feed_dict={dequeue_placeholder: dequeue_handle.handle})
        val2 = sess.run(compute_op2, feed_dict={dequeue_placeholder: dequeue_handle.handle})
        size = sess.run(size_op)
        print("val1 %d, val2 %d, queue size %d" % (val1, val2, size))
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print("Done")
```

You should see something like below when you run it

```
val1 1, val2 2, queue size 9
val1 2, val2 3, queue size 8
val1 3, val2 4, queue size 7
val1 4, val2 5, queue size 6
val1 5, val2 6, queue size 5
val1 6, val2 7, queue size 4
val1 7, val2 8, queue size 3
val1 8, val2 9, queue size 2
val1 9, val2 10, queue size 1
val1 10, val2 11, queue size 0
Done
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the size of my input tensor is variable in the first dimension between batches. This is because we work with molecular data, and molecules each have different numbers of atoms, unlike image data, where all images are a fixed size. So, I don't think using a tf.Variable will work, since these have to be fixed size.

Comment: Hm, how are you using a queue? Queues are similar to variables in that they allocate a fixed size buffer

Comment: There are many solutions depending on how exactly your problem is structured, so this question would need more details. In general choices are 1) pad things to fit in a fixed size variable, 2) use strings which can put variable amount of data into fixed dimension tensor 3) cache an intermediate stage which is fixed size instead of variable size input 4) use persistent tensors to save variable-size tensor between run calls

Comment: Here is a short example. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/333e9e94f8d5143a9229064e511ae1ef

The output is: 
(5619, 194) (100, 1)
(4962, 194) (100, 1)

Basically, my system uses a custom batch iterator class to group subsets of the data together into variable length batch tensors and enqueue them (all in a separate thread).

Comment: I don't really like the idea of padding, just because some molecules are very small (a few atoms) and some are very large (50+ atoms), making for a whole lot of wasted memory and computation.

Comment: Updated answer with variable size solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Persistent tensors is exactly what I was looking for. It's probably worth noting that this code does not work on v0.08, but after upgrading to v0.12 (finally) it does work.

Comment: btw, 0.12rc0 is broken in a [subtle way](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6059) I'd recommend using 0.11 or waiting for 0.12rc1

Comment: Any idea why I might be getting the following error:

Invalid argument: The tensor with handle 'GetSessionHandle;10;/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0' is not in the session store.

This seems to only occur when I try to run enqueue and dequeue operations on different threads.

Comment: could it be that the tensor got deleted? By default it deletes all unreferenced tensors every 10 tensor allocations. Also, default graph is thread local, so when you create new ops in a new thread, they will be appended to a new graph

Comment: Yep. It was deleting them. Looks like you have to maintain a reference to the session tensor itself returned from the dequeue_op. Unfortunately, if you just maintain a reference to each T.handle, the original tensors get deleted at garbage collection.

Comment: Correct, TensorHandle implements __del__ method which gets called when the object is no longer referenced. It would be harder to have this behavior T.handle since those are regular Python strings

Comment: is it possible to use this for queues with multiple tensors? for example, if my queue takes the tuple [tf.string, tf.int32] and I want to be able to advance this queue once but have multiple session.run's firing on the string and int data.

when I try with your technique, I'm getting stuck because tf.tf.get_session_handle won't process the tuple of tensors that comes back from my dequeue() operation