# TensorFlow: Specifying storage of layer activations

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Motivation:** It's easy to imagine a scenario where one could amass a large number of layers so as to overwhelm a GPU's memory capacity.

A potential solution to this issue would be to take advantage of any backwards computability between layers. I.e. layer `j`'s output is a function of the next layers output:

[image]

Here you could simply store the final such layer activation in memory and compute activations in a 'trickle back' fashion during backprop.

---

**Problem:** I'm unfamiliar with manual memory management in TensorFlow and haven't been able to find information on how one might go about specifying what variables TensorFlow should keep in memory and which can be discarded.

The other side of implementing this is specifying a custom gradient computation; this I feel is well-enough documented and should be achievable. However, if anyone has any caveats related to this, I'd appreciate hearing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you want to save memory by discarding intermediate results and recomputing them later. I can see two potential approaches. One is to rewire the graph to do this recomputation, and another is to use persistent tensors for intermediate results and control their deletion manually.

For the first approach, consider the following computation and its gradient graph.

[image]

You use `contrib.graph_editor` to modify the graph as follows.

[image]

Note that now it's possible to pick an execution order which only needs enough memory for 2 activations. However, TensorFlow typically does not pick this execution order, and instead computes both `a2` tensors in the beginning, hence requiring enough memory to store 4 activations at peak. (see [caterpillar graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5816#issuecomment-268710077) for an extreme example).

The solution is to add control dependencies to force a particular execution order.

[image]

This would force second `a2` node to be computed after `b3`. Since TensorFlow releases memory as soon as the tensor is no longer needed, all execution orders in this graph need enough peak memory to store 2 activations instead of 3.

Here's a [notebook](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/notebooks/blob/master/simple_rewiring.ipynb) that implements the example above.

If the computation that goes a2->a3 is invertible, you would rewire your graph as follows

[image]

The second approach would be to use Persistent Tensors. You can tell TensorFlow to keep certain tensors after the run call completes. Unlike Variables, these objects can be deleted to free the memory. You have a downside of more `.run` calls, each incurring additional 200 usec delay per run call, but it may be easier than all the graph rewiring. I haven't explored this route, but here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001298/decouple-dequeue-operation-from-gradient-loss-computation/41002892#41002892) of using persistent tensors  (deletion is done using [delete_session_tensor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard0/tf.delete_session_tensor.md) command)

Comment: Very well answered; much appreciated!

Comment: For your last two graphs: they show `a2` being computed from `a1`'s activation, but w.r.t. my question it should be computed from `a3` as `a2 = f(a3)` for some function f, correct?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, you are saying that your layers are invertible, and you actually can compute them backwards? Then yes, you would need to add wiring to do something like a2 = f(a3). ReluGrad is a standard example, you can compute gradient of ReLU from output instead of input. It seems hard for the most intensive parts -- for matmul and convolution layers going backwards would need matrix inverse