# How can I keep state from train step to train step?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor in my computation graph that I'd like to add a row to after every train step. How can I accomplish this?

More detail: I'm grabbing gradients from `optimizer.compute_gradients`, and I'd like to modify those gradients based on the gradient history. Here is the code that I'm trying to use:

```python
def process_gradient(gradient, optimizer, name):
  reshaped_gradient = flatten(gradient)

  if gradient.name in optimizer._slots:
    optimizer._slots[gradient.name] += [reshaped_gradient]
  else:
    optimizer._slots[gradient.name] = [reshaped_gradient]

  # each 
  gradients_over_time = tf.stack(optimizer._slots[gradient.name])

  print('gradients_over_time.get_shape()', gradients_over_time.get_shape())

  return gradient

...

grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost_function)
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients([(process_gradient(grad, optimizer, str(i)), var) for i, (grad, var) in enumerate(grads_and_vars)])
```

I've also tried keeping a variable around that I use to keep track of rows by concatenating new rows onto, but that didn't work.

Comment: You could use persistent tensors to save tensors between run calls, see Solution #2 for example usage in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001298/decouple-dequeue-operation-from-gradient-loss-computation

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `tf.py_func` to accomplish this. I keep track of state in a global list that is accessed in the Python function. Here the gradients are applied:

```
# process each individual gradient before applying it
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients([(process_gradient(grad, str(i)), var) for i, (grad, var) in enumerate(grads_and_vars)])
```

Here is where I keep track of state over time, and would use the built up state:

```
def construct_processor(name):
  global_gradients_over_time = {}

  def python_process_gradient(gradient):
    reshaped_gradient = gradient.flatten()

    if name in global_gradients_over_time:
      global_gradients_over_time[name].append(reshaped_gradient)
    else:
      global_gradients_over_time[name] = [reshaped_gradient]

    # process gradients somehow

    return gradient

  return python_process_gradient

def process_gradient(gradient, name):
  return tf.py_func(construct_processor(name), [gradient], tf.float32)
```

`construct_processor` is just there to allow you to process gradients one at a time, giving each set of gradients a name so I can find them in the global dictionary. This approach also keeps memory off the GPU, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using persistent Tensors to store gradient history. In the loop below `gradient_history` refers to concatenation of all the gradients so far:

```
n = 2
x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((n,)))
x_target = 10*tf.ones((n,))
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x - x_target))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
gradient = tf.gradients(loss, [x])[0]
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients([[gradient, x]])

# initialize history with first gradient
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
gradient_history0 = sess.run(tf.get_session_handle(tf.stack([gradient])))
previous_gradients_in, previous_gradients = tf.get_session_tensor(gradient_history0, dtype=dtype)
gradient_history = tf.concat(0, [previous_gradients, [gradient]])
gradient_history_out = tf.get_session_handle(gradient_history)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(10):
    [gradient_history0, _, loss0, gradient0] = sess.run([gradient_history_out, train_op, loss, gradient],
                                                   feed_dict={previous_gradients_in: gradient_history0.handle})
    print(loss0, gradient0)
```

When you run it, you should see something like this:

```
200.0 [-20. -20.]
128.0 [-16. -16.]
81.92 [-12.80000019 -12.80000019]
52.4288 [-10.23999977 -10.23999977]
33.5544 [-8.19199944 -8.19199944]
21.4748 [-6.55359936 -6.55359936]
13.7439 [-5.24287987 -5.24287987]
8.79609 [-4.19430351 -4.19430351]
5.6295 [-3.35544205 -3.35544205]
3.60288 [-2.68435287 -2.68435287]
```

Note that at each fed step of your computation, `gradient_history` is a Tensor object which refers to gradient history. Meanwhile `gradient_history0` is a TensorHandle object which refers to the saved history which persists between `session.run` calls. You can feed that value back into the graph using `feed_dict={...: gradient_history0.handle}`, but unlike feeding numpy arrays, you are feeding in a "pointer" to the data, and the data itself never leaves TensorFlow runtime. Since the handle persists between `session.run` calls, you can also evaluate it directly:

```
In [10]: gradient_history0.eval()
Out[10]:
array([[-20.        , -20.        ],
       [-20.        , -20.        ],
       [-16.        , -16.        ],
       [-12.80000019, -12.80000019],
       [-10.23999977, -10.23999977],
       [ -8.19199944,  -8.19199944],
       [ -6.55359936,  -6.55359936],
       [ -5.24287987,  -5.24287987],
       [ -4.19430351,  -4.19430351],
       [ -3.35544205,  -3.35544205],
       [ -2.68435287,  -2.68435287]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently parsing it. Why did you use `tf.gradients` instead of `optimizer.compute_gradients`?

Comment: No special reason, they should be the same

Comment: What is the purpose of the feed dictionary in your example?

Comment: That's how you feed previous gradients into the session to concatenate with new gradient

Comment: `previous_gradients_in` depends on `gradient_history0` but nothing appears to depend on `previous_gradients_in`. Why is that? What's the point of a placeholder that isn't used? Is it being used in some hidden way?

Comment: `previous_gradients_in` is connected to `previous_gradients`, the connection is done by `tf.get_session_tensor`