# tensorflow buffering data from asynchronous sub-graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow

**tl;dr** How do we effectively buffer the outputs of unfed subgraphs across multiple runs in a single session?

In tensorflow we are attempting to feed an 'output' model from several 'input' models (which are really acting as preprocessors for the output graph). For later ease we would hope to implement this as a single tensorflow graph. The input models receive data at very different rates, with, for example, one being a consistent per-minute time series and another being a clustering algorithm that may only update once a day. Each new input is fed as a python dict into a new run in the same session, and the output model is expected to update with every new input datum. Given this is a stateful system with historical dependence, it is vital to maintain the sequence of inputs.

Currently we are having issues with how to, essentially, concat the input models' outputs. The issue being is that we cannot seem to effectively buffer most of the input layers outputs and only update the one we now have data for.

We have tried: variable assigns, which lead to an iteration-out-of-date data being delivered to the output, FIFO queues, which seem to get very complex for such a simple task, and partial_run()'s which have to be re-setup() each time a input model updates, mostly defeating the point.

We would like it so this buffering solution is compatible with feeding large sets of input data for, e.g. training, but it is not a hard requirement for this setup.

This all used to be implemented with a python buffer that would pull data from completely separated model and manually create an input vector for the output model. This works, of course, but seems unnecessarily clunky and will become over-complex when adding in more input models.

Toy example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ilayera_in     = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
ilayera_out    = tf.reduce_mean(ilayera_in, axis=-1)

ilayerb_in      = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
ilayerb_out     = tf.reduce_mean(ilayerb_in, axis=-1)

# this is where the 'buffering' should take place.
olayer_in      = tf.concat([[ilayera_out], [ilayerb_out]], axis=0)

olayer_out     = tf.reduce_max(olayer_in)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayera_in: [[1, 1, 1]], ilayerb_in: [[1, 1, 1]]}))  # 1
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayera_in: [[2, 2, 2]], ilayerb_in: [[3, 3, 3]]}))  # 3
    # tf will, of course, raise an exception on the next line. how can i reuse
    # the *result* of the previous run of ilayerb with the new result of ilayera
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayera_in: [[1, 1, 1]]}))  # 3
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayera_in: [[5, 5, 5]]}))  # 5
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayerb_in: [[3, 3, 3]]}))  # 5
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayerb_in: [[4, 4, 4]]}))  # 5
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayera_in: [[1, 1, 1]]}))  # 4
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayera_in: [[1, 1, 1]], ilayerb_in: [[1, 1, 1]]}))  # 1
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayera_in: [[1, 1, 1]]}))  # 3
    print(sess.run(olayer_out, feed_dict={ilayerb_in: [[3, 3, 3]]}))  # 3
```

Comment: Queues seem like a logical approach. Also, if you want to reuse your previous Python based architecture, you could get outputs of session.run calls as persistent tensors. This is similar to numpy arrays -- you'll have Python objects referring to the data, but the actual data is stored in numpy/TensorFlow arrays

Comment: I had previously tried queues but it seemed to get rather complex quickly for what seems to be a simple activity (indicating I'm doing it wrong). Do you have some links to relevant examples? Also I haven't come across the term 'persistent tensors', could you explain more?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643637/how-can-i-keep-state-from-train-step-to-train-step/41645904#41645904) of using persistent tensor. Things have improved since then, you can feed persistent tensor directly into computational graph with feed_dict (no need to use get_session_tensor op)

Comment: Basically persistent tensor gives a way to "fetch result of session.run, save in Python queue, feed it back int using `feed_dict`", without the performance hit you get when using numpy arrays

Comment: Thank you for your help so far :) . While persistent tensors look interesting and may help with other issues, I don't really see how they can help with the complexity of using a python-buffering solution (though they certainly help with the inefficiency of it).