# Cache intermediate tensor and update periodically

Tags: tensorflow

I have a large tensor that is expensive to calculate, but realistically I only need to recalculate it every 10 iterations or so (during gradient descent). What's the best way to do this?

More specifically:

Suppose I have an `intermediate_tensor` that is used in the calculation of `final_tensor` each time the a `tf.Session` is run. `final_tensor` is, in my case, a set of modified gradients to use in optimization. It is possible to define a graph that contains both `intermediate_tensor` and `final_tensor`. However, running this graph will be inefficient when `intermediate_tensor` changes slowly. In pseudocode, this is what I'd like to do:

```
intermediate_tensor = tf.some_operation(earlier_variable)
final_tensor = tf.matmul(intermediate_tensor, other_earlier_variable)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # pretending `partial_run` works like I want it to:
    sess.partial_run(intermediate_tensor, feed_dict = {})
    for i in range(5):
       ft = sess.partial_run(final_tensor, feed_dict = {})
       print(ft)
```

The experimental `partial_run` feature is *almost* what I'm looking for. However, `partial_run` can only be used if I want to evaluate `final_tensor` just once for each time I evaluate `intemediate_tensor`. It won't work for a for loop.

My workaround for the moment is to use `tf.placeholder`. I evaluate `intermediate_tensor` in one call to `sess.run`, then feed the result to a new call of `sess.run` as a placeholder. However, this is very inflexible. It requires that I hardcode the variable shape at compile time, for example. It's also not very good when the number of intermediate variables I'd like to use is very large.

Is there a better way? This would be very helpful if, say, one were using a curvature matrix that doesn't need to be evaluated every iteration.

Comment: You can use regular run and `feed_dict` to feed in values. Use persistent tensor (ie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001298/decouple-dequeue-operation-from-gradient-loss-computation/41002892#41002892)) to avoid copying things in/out of TF runtime

Comment: Persistent tensors! exactly what I was looking for.